# How to get value of selectcheckboxmenu in javascript

Tags: javascript, primefaces

Here my code,

```
 function validateForm()   
    {
        var messages = [];

        if (document.getElementById("templateForm:create:assignTo").value=="")
        {
            messages.push("Assigned Person must be filled out.");
        }
        if (messages.length > 0) {
            alert(messages.join('\n'));
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } 
<p:selectCheckboxMenu widgetVar="Name" value="#{Bean.assignedPersons}" label="#{Bean.assignedPersonLabel}" id="assignTo" styleClass="form-control" style="width:300px" required="true" requiredMessage="!">
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{Bean.employeeNameList}" />  
                                        <p:ajax oncomplete="PF('Name').show()" listener="#{Bean.populateLabel2()}" update="assignTo" ></p:ajax> 
                                        <p:ajax event="toggleSelect" oncomplete="PF('Name').show()" listener="#{Bean.populateLabel2()}" update="assignTo"></p:ajax> 
                                    </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

I'm try to get value of selectcheckboxmenu, But i always get 'underfined'.
How to do to get this value,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the answer, My target is to check validation with javascript. Selectcheckboxmenu is multi select option. So, i think to get value is impossible. That's why i got 'underfined'. Now i tried with total check count of selectcheckboxmenu.
Here my code,

```
var o = document.getElementById("templateForm:updateAMCTaskProfile:assignTo").getElementsByTagName('input');
        for ( var i in o ) {
            if ( o[i].type=='checkbox' ) {
                if ( o[i].checked ) {
                    cnt++;
                }
            }
        }
        if(cnt == 0)
        {
            messages.push("Assign person must be filled out.");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use id of the selectedMenu

```
document.getElementById("assignTo").value==""
```

Comment: Cannot use like that, because this selectedMenu is under some form id.

Answer (score 0):

In primefaces to access the js object you can use the PF(widgetVar), in this case you can do as follow:

To get the checked input

```
PF('Name').inputs.filter(':checked')
```

To get the values of this checked input

```
PF('Name').inputs.filter(':checked').each(function({
                                        alert($(this).val());
                                     });
```

*The inputs attribute is for Primefaces internal use, pay attention on how use it.*